# how to have the possibility to chose between the frequency of the locationupdates(every seconds,minutes etc..)?

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, locationlistener

Hello i just wanted to know how can i modify the frequency of location updates by clicking on a menu item 
i tried this but it doesn't seem that what i am doing here is good (code added below) because i dont get location updates in the chosen frequency.
i just want to know if it possible to change the frequency and whats the best way to implement. 
i want to be able to refresh location : only once , every sec or every 2 min  by clicking on a sub menu item.
item selection is in the end

Can anyone tell me plz if what i am doing is right and of not let me know how i can do it?
Thanks in advance

Here is the code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;


import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

 public class MapLocator extends MapActivity implements LocationListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */


 private LocationManager lm;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);

    mapView = (MapView) this.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    mc = mapView.getController();
    mc.setZoom(14);



    int FIVE_MINUTES = 5 /*Minutes*/ * 60 /*sec per min*/ * 1000 /*ms per sec*/;
    lm = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,  FIVE_MINUTES, 0, this);


    Drawable drawable= this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.loc_seven);
    ListItimizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new ListItimizedOverlay(drawable);
    GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint(33000000,84000000);
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(p, "Hello from", "Tahiti");
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlayItem(overlayitem);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(itemizedoverlay);

 }


 @Override
 protected boolean isRouteDisplayed()
 {
 return false;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
 {
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_S)
     {
         mapView.setSatellite(!mapView.isSatellite());
         return true;
     }
 return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }

 @Override
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
 {
     Log.d("msg","1");

     lat = location.getLatitude();
     lng = location.getLongitude();

        Toast.makeText(
                getBaseContext(),
                "Location change to : Latitude = " + lat + " Longitude = "
                    + lng, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6));
     mc.animateTo(p);
     mc.setCenter(p);
     mc.setZoom(14);
     Drawable drawable= this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.loc_seven);
     ListItimizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new ListItimizedOverlay(drawable);
     OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(p, "", "");
     itemizedoverlay=  (ListItimizedOverlay ) mapView.getOverlays().get(0);
     itemizedoverlay.clear();
     itemizedoverlay.addOverlayItem(overlayitem);
     mapView.getOverlays().add(itemizedoverlay);


 }

 @Override
 public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
 {
     if(provider.equals("LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER")){
         Toast.makeText(MapLocator.this, "GPS is off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
         }

     }

 @Override
 public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
 {

    Log.v("main", "Enabled");
        Toast.makeText(MapLocator.this, "GPS Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }

 @Override
 public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
 {
 }

 @Override
 public void onPause() {
     super.onPause();
     lm.removeUpdates(this);
     }

  //Méthode qui se déclenchera lorsque vous appuierez sur le bouton menu du téléphone
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu2) {

        //Création d'un MenuInflater qui va permettre d'instancier un Menu XML en un objet Menu
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        //Instanciation du menu XML spécifier en un objet Menu
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.menumap, menu2);

        return true;
     }


 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         //On regarde quel item a été cliqué grâce à son id et on déclenche une action

          switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.refresh:
                return true;

            case R.id.refreshonce:

                 this.lm.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, this, null);
                 Toast.makeText(MapLocator.this, "refreshnow", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;

            case R.id.refresheachsec:

                this.lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,  0, 0, this);
                 Toast.makeText(MapLocator.this, "refresh2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;   

            case R.id.refresheach2min:

                this.lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,  2*60*1000, 0, this);
                 Toast.makeText(MapLocator.this, "refresh2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;        


            case R.id.refresheach5min:

                this.lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,  5*60*1000, 0, this);
                 Toast.makeText(MapLocator.this, "refresh5", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;   

           case R.id.quitter:

               finish();
               return true;
         }
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the minimum time interval is effectively a suggestion. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String, long, float, android.location.LocationListener)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `LocationManager.removeUpdates()` before requesting updates with a new timing.  Also note that in JellyBean (4.1) the minimum time between updates is no longer just a hint.

Please See:[Location Manager in Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)

"Prior to Jellybean, the minTime parameter was only a hint, and some location provider implementations ignored it. From Jellybean and onwards it is mandatory for Android compatible devices to observe both the minTime and minDistance parameters."